# Cron strange behaviour

Tags: linux, cron, bash-scripting, crontab, cronjob

I've got a Bash script with all the permission to be excecuted, I attach it to to a cron job, this script basically only kills and restarts a specific process. The strange behaviour is that if I run the script via terminal everything works fine as expected, it shuts down the process and restarts it. But when the cron job is triggered it only shuts down the process and nothing more...any idea why this behaviour occur?

Comment: If you don't post some details (cron definition, script content...) it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 5):

Keep in mind that a script running in *cron* does not have the same environment as a script running in *shell*.

The cron daemon starts a subshell from your HOME directory.

The cron daemon supplies a default environment for every shell, defining `HOME`, `LOGNAME`, `SHELL` (=`/usr/bin/sh`) and `PATH` (=`/usr/bin`).

Do not depend on environment variables. This includes path setting, x11 settings, or anything else.

Use full path, for example:

instead of simply calling `java` or `python` you have to use `/usr/bin/java` or `/usr/bin/python`.

Comment: Or, just specify a decent value for `PATH` as part of your cron spec...